# Redux subscribed called for entire state

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers

I've got two reducers, **redA** and **redB**. I've also got two controllers **ctrlA** and **ctrlB**.

Currently, when a change in state happens in either **redA** or **redB**, because both **ctrlA** and **ctrlB** have both invoked `store.subsribe()`, they both get notified when a change happens in the state regardless of what reducer caused it.

Is there a way to only notify the controllers based on which reducer made the change ( or maybe even better, notify them on a per action basis? )

Or is this a bug in my way of thinking of REDUX? I'd be grateful to hear your opionions. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is too broad... maybe a snippet showing real code, expected vs, actual behavior.

Comment: You just need to check the subscribed method, so you can check if the actual value you need is changing. On the other hand, the controllers shouldn't know about the actions, at least in the "redux" world. Redux should take care of action types and what to do with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how Redux works.  Redux does not have different change events for different parts of its state.  In fact, subscription callbacks are run *every* time an action reaches the root reducer function, even if *nothing* is changed as a result of that dispatched action.

Redux simply notifies subscribers that an action was dispatched, and now it's up to the subscribers to determine what they want to do based on the current state.  Usually that involves diffing the current state vs the old state, and React-Redux's `connect()` function generates wrapper components that do that for you automatically.

So yes, if you have two different components that are subscribed to the store, each of them will be notified whenever an action is dispatched, even if `state.a` was updated and the component is only interested in `state.b`.

Also, it's a bad idea to "manually" subscribe to the store.  I wrote a long comment [explaining why you should use `connect()` to interact with the Redux store in a React app](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6hperk/i_use_react_and_redux_but_never_reactredux_what/dj0fywb/).

**edit**

Here's an example of how a subscriber could diff state:

```
let prevState;

store.subscribe(() => {
    const currState = store.getState();
    const stateHasChanged = !_.isEqual(currState, prevState);

    prevState = currState;
});
```

That's not how you should do it in production, but it shows the basic idea: keep a reference to the old state, get the current state, do some kind of comparison between the two.

Comment: Thank you, currently im only using vanilla js to try and get a good understanding of REDUX before moving to React. The main question here is, how would the subscriber know what caused the state change? As far as i understand, the action that caused the state change isnt returned in subscribe and it'd feel kinda wrong to just store a variable with the last invoked action.

How would you go about it on vanilla JS?

Comment: Also, fwiw: normally we recommend doing things the other way around - learning React first, and _then_ learning Redux.  That said, you should feel free to tackle them in whichever order you want.